# Problemas para insertar datos a oracle realice conexion con oracle pero me tira este error returning "ID" into

Tags: laravel, oracle, excel

El problema que tengo creo que es de sintaxis o codigo ya que con mysql si me insertaba correctamente pero ahorita que realice una conexion con oracle ya no me inserta los datos y me tira el siguiente error realice una consulta normal para ver si el problema era la conexion y no es eso por que si me inserto bien los datos esta es la consulta que puse como prueba en un controlador y si me funciona y no se si es el metodo que estoy realizando o que podra ser

```
  $users=DB::INSERT('Insert into fcm_enl_ter_fact values(\'JUAN\',\'Enlace\',\'DICAHSA _PROFORMA\',65890,25,\'\',\'\',SYSDATE,\'D\',24.8211)');
```

pero al momento de realizarlo con el metodo de importacion de excel que lo tenia con mysql me da el siguiente error ala hora de insertar los datos

**Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Exceptions\Oci8Exception 
Error Code : 904 Error Message : ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier Position : 238 Statement : insert into "FCM_ENL_TER_FACT" ("PROVEEDOR", "DESC_ENLACE", "NO_FACTURA", "ID_ENLACE", "VALOR_PAGO", "PERIODO", "FECHA_FACTURA", "FECHA_INGRESO", "MONEDA", "TC_FACTURA") values (:p0, :p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9) returning "ID" into :p10 Bindings : [JUAN,Enlace de Cobre,DICAHSA _PROFORMA,66916,23,,,SYSDATE,D,24.8211,0]**

**este es mi modelo en el cual hago referencia a mi tabla**

```
  <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class importar extends Model
{

    protected $table="fcm_enl_ter_fact";

    protected  $fillable  = [
        'PROVEEDOR','DESC_ENLACE','NO_FACTURA','ID_ENLACE','VALOR_PAGO','PERIODO','FECHA_FACTURA','FECHA_INGRESO','MONEDA','TC_FACTURA'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**estas son mis rutas**

```
Route::GET('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::POST('cargar_datos_usuarios',[
    'as'=>'cargar_datos_usuarios',
    'uses'=>'importarexcel@cargar_datos_usuarios'
]);
```

**Esta es mi clase donde identifico las columnas de mi excel**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

namespace App\Imports;

use App\importar;
use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\HeadingRowFormatter;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper;
Use DB;

HeadingRowFormatter::default('none');

class Usersimport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{


    public function model(array $row)
    {
//
        var_dump($row);
//        insertGetId

        return new importar([



            "PROVEEDOR" => $row['PROVEEDOR'],
            "DESC_ENLACE" => $row['DESC_ENLACE'],
            "NO_FACTURA" => $row['NO_FACTURA'],
            "ID_ENLACE" => $row['ID_ENLACE'],
            "VALOR_PAGO" => $row['VALOR_PAGO'],
            "PERIODO" => $row['PERIODO'],
            "FECHA_FACTURA" => $row['FECHA_FACTURA'],
            "FECHA_INGRESO" => $row['FECHA_INGRESO'],
            "MONEDA" => $row['MONEDA'],
            'TC_FACTURA' => $row['TC_FACTURA']
        ]);
    }
}
```

**este es mi controlador donde inserto los datos**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Imports\Usersimport;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
//use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
use App\importar;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

Use DB;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper;

class importarexcel extends Controller
{

    public function cargar_datos_usuarios(Request $request)
    {


        $file=$request->file('file');
        //insertGetId()
//        var_dump($file);

        Excel::Import(new Usersimport,$file);
//        insertGetId()

        return back()->with('message','Importacion de usuarios completado');

    }
```

---

En esta parte identifico mis datos de excel y de igual forma identifico mis campos de mi tabla de la base de datos

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

namespace App\Imports;

use App\importar;
use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\HeadingRowFormatter;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper;
Use DB;

HeadingRowFormatter::default('none');

class Usersimport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{


    public function model(array $row)
    {


        return new importar([



            "PROVEEDOR" => $row['PROVEEDOR'],
            "DESC_ENLACE" => $row['DESC_ENLACE'],
            "NO_FACTURA" => $row['NO_FACTURA'],
            "ID_ENLACE" => $row['ID_ENLACE'],
            "VALOR_PAGO" => $row['VALOR_PAGO'],
            "PERIODO" => $row['PERIODO'],
            "FECHA_FACTURA" => $row['FECHA_FACTURA'],
            "FECHA_INGRESO" => $row['FECHA_INGRESO'],
            "MONEDA" => $row['MONEDA'],
            'TC_FACTURA' => $row['TC_FACTURA'],

        ]);
    }
}
```

Una vez identificados los datos pasan al controlador donde los inserto

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Imports\Usersimport;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
//use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
use App\importar;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

Use DB;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper;

class importarexcel extends Controller
{

    public function cargar_datos_usuarios(Request $request)
    {


        $file=$request->file('file');


        Excel::Import(new Usersimport,$file);



        return back()->with('message','Importacion de usuarios completado');

    }
```

Comment: estas usando el miso query para myql que para oracle?

Comment: si es correcto ahi donde tengo el controlador donde llamo los datos de mi excel no se como puedo resolverlo o como iria ahi con oracle por que pienso que ahi donde tengo ese arreglo tengo el problema

Comment: Hay que arreglar el query... no es lo mismo mysql que oracle. Mostra el query

Comment: No tengo query ya que utilizo la libreria de importacion de excel ahi te describire en el codigo donde llamo los datos y donde inserto colocare lo que utilizo modificare el codigo con lo que utilizo para que me entiendas mejor

Comment: Ahi lo modifique para ver si me ayudas ya que no entiendo mucho con oracle y llevo bastante tiempo viendo como poder realizarlo a oracle

Comment: No entiendo que tiene que ver excel con oracle? Quien genera esa query? Donde es que mandas los datos a oracle y como lo haces?

Comment: Ahi deje el controlador donde triago los datos de mi excel y posteriormente identifico los datos de mi tabla para poder insertarlos ahi deje como lo realizo

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar... donde generas esa query? o la genera laravel automaticamente? le dijiste en algun lado que cambiaste mysql por oracle? en oracle no es returning, es returning into.

Comment: Bueno la query la genera laravel por que yo descargue el paquete de oracle para laravel para realizar la conexion y query en si no la desarrollo solo realice los pasos que estan en mi codigo que coloque y una vez identifico los datos ahi paso al controlador y me inserta los datos ahi esta en el codigo lo que realizo

Comment: ahi coloque en una respuesta donde se realiza ese proceso de insercion para ver si me hechas la mano

Comment: no, las respuestas son respuestas a tu problema. las ediciones van en la pregunta.

Comment: Y no puedo ayudarte mucho mas, sigo sin entender que tiene que ver excel en este proceso, y como configuraste laravel para conectarse a oracle (y no soy experto en laravel).

Comment: Bueno lo que trato de realizar es importar datos de una hoja de excel a mi base de datos oracle utilizando laravel

Comment: Por ejemplo en la clase donde identifico los campos de mi hoja de excel y de mi base de datos no se como puedo hacer para que no me inserte un ID el cual me dice que no esta en mi tabla de base de datos y no se como puedo indicarle en esa parte que me desabilite eso de insertar el ID ya que ese es el problema y no se por que me dice que me lo inserta como algo ya definido

Answer (score 0):

El error que te genera es porque en tu tabla `fcm_enl_ter_fact` no existe la columna `id`, como el error te lo indica:

**Error Message : ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier**

Porque al final de la sentencia que ejecuta le agrega un returning id:

```
insert into "FCM_ENL_TER_FACT" ("PROVEEDOR", 
"DESC_ENLACE", "NO_FACTURA", "ID_ENLACE", 
"VALOR_PAGO", "PERIODO", "FECHA_FACTURA", 
"FECHA_INGRESO", "MONEDA", "TC_FACTURA") values 
(:p0, :p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9) **returning "ID"** into :p10 Bindings
```

---

**Solución**

En el model de laravel debes colocar la siguiente linea

```php
public $incrementing = false;
```

Con eso le indicas que el primary key de tu tabla asociada al modelo no es auto-increment.

Comment: Si eso miro pero no se como quitarle eso que no lo agregue por que yo no le indico que me lo agregue el returning ID no se como puedo hacer eso que no me agregue o inserte ese id ya que en mi tabla no existe no se como resolver ese problema

Comment: si me puedes indicar como hacerlo aqui en mi codigo para evitar ese problema por que no se como hacerlo nunca habia visto ese problema

Comment: Según lo que he leído tienes que colocar esta linea en el model `public $incrementing = false;` en tu caso tu modelo es  `importar`

Comment: Lo coloque como me dijiste y al parecer el error desaparecio pero me tira otro error Error Code : 1841 Error Message : ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0 Position  sera por que es otro tipo de error

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias al parecer es problema de fecha y la quite y me funciono me has sacado de algo que me tenia desesperado agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: Voy a colocarlo en la respuesta con la explicación